# SKLabelNode is not appearing on SKSpriteNode swift

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm trying to add a SKLabelNode as a child of SKSpriteNode:

```
var mainNode = SKSpriteNode()

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    mainNode = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.redColor(), size: self.size)
    mainNode.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
    mainNode.zPosition = -2
    mainNode.name = "MainNode"
    self.addChild(mainNode)

    let myLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed:"Chalkduster")
    myLabel.text = "Hello, World!"
    myLabel.fontSize = 45
    myLabel.position = CGPoint(x:CGRectGetMidX(mainNode.frame), y:CGRectGetMidY(mainNode.frame))

    mainNode.addChild(myLabel)
}
```

But the SKLabelNode is not appearing. I tried to change its zPosition, but it doesn't work anyway.

If I add label on the scene itself (`self.addChild(myLabel)`) it works just fine

Comment: In `viewDidLoad` in the view controller, add `scene.size = view.frame.size` in the `if let scene ...` block and set the position of `myLabel` to `CGPointZero`.

Comment: @0x141E, thanks, that worked! Please, post this as answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that `CGPoint(x:CGRectGetMidX(mainNode.frame), y:CGRectGetMidY(mainNode.frame))` put your label out of bounds. So If you want your SKLabelNode horizontally and vertically centered, you can simply do it like this

```
let myLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed:"Chalkduster")
myLabel.text = "Hello, World!"
myLabel.fontSize = 45
myLabel.horizontalAlignmentMode = .Center
myLabel.verticalAlignmentMode = .Center
mainNode.addChild(myLabel)
```